# Tabulator: Fix position of right most column when adjusting table column width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tabulator

How do i fix the position of the right most column?

When trying to increase or decrease the size of a column, the right most column moves along with the adjustment, creating a gap or a horizontal scroll bar in the process. Is there a way to adjust all the columns dynamically to allow the position of the right most column to stay fixed?

Here are a few examples from [the docs](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.8)

Gap from decreasing 3rd column width:
[image: Gap from decreasing column width]

Scroll bar from increasing 3rd column width:
[image: scroll bar from increasing column width]

Answer (score 0):

#### Layout Mode

If you want columns to resize then you should look at using the ***fitColumns*** layout mode. in the table constructor you should set this on the `layout` option:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
});
```

This can be seen on the [Fit To Width Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.8#fittowidth)

Tabulator provides many options for configuring this layout mode to choose how to resize each column. More info on this can be found in the [Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/layout#fittowidth)

#### Frozen Columns

If you would alternatively like the column to remain where it is, even when the table is scrolled horizontally then you can use the `frozen` property on the column definition for the `dob` column to freeze it in place:

```js
{title:"Date of Birth", field:"dob", frozen:true}}
```

More details on this can be found in the [Frozen Columns DOcumentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/layout#frozen-column)

Comment: Hi Oli, fitColumns does not solve the issue.

For example when trying to resize the second column, the last column moves along with it and creates a horizontal bar or a gap. Is there a way to fix the last column in place such that the last column does not move on resizing of the other columns?

Comment: No, this is not possible at the moment. But will be comming in one of the next two releases